# Comparar valores em duas tabelas com php e Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, lógica

Tenho que comparar se os números da tabela A existe na tabela B sendo que se existir faz uma instrução senão faz outra. Tentei isso e não funcionou, não retorna nada no else.

Obs: Na tabela B pode não existir o `codigo` da tabela A

EXEMPLO:

```
TABELA A campo => (codigo): 12,13,23,44,55
TABELA B campo => (meucampo): 13,44,55


$sql_A="SELECT * FROM A"; 
$resultado_A = $conexao->query($sql_A);
while($row_A = $resultado_A->fetch_assoc()) : ?>


    $sql_B="SELECT * FROM B WHERE meucampo = ".$row_A['codigo']." "; 
    $resultado_B = $conexao->query($sql_B);

        while($row_B = $resultado_B->fetch_assoc()) :

            if($row_A['codigo'] == $row_b['meucampo'])  :
                echo"<a href='link'>foo</a>";
                else   :
                echo"<a href='link'>foo/bar</a>";

            endif;

        endwhile; 

endwhile;
```

Comment: Faça um outer join com ON comparando todos os campos, com WHERE IS NULL() dois dois lados. Só vai retornar o que for diferente. (mas cuidado, que em casos onde houver mais de uma linha idêntica dos dois lados não tem como diferenciar) - Outra alternativa é fazer dois SELECTS separados, ordenados por algum campo, e ir dando fetch row do lado que tiver mais "atrasado", e comparando. Se forem iguais, dá fetch dos 2 lados. Se forem diferentes, anote a linha, e avance a menor das duas na ordenação. É prático e rápido, e não precisa acumular tudo na memória.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Bacco. Fiz assim mas sem sucesso to vendo outras maneiras. SELECT * FROM categoriassub OUTER JOIN categorias ON categoriassub.categoria = categorias.codigo WHERE categoria.codigo IS NULL. Se for possível apresentar exemplo prático agradeço. Estou testando outras maneiras.

Comment: Nesse seu código não está "comparando todos os campos" e não tem "IS NULL() dos dois lados"

Comment: Eu acho que se a query resultar zero registros, o while não será sequer executado, não entrando até o seu IF código == meucampo, então faça a checagem com numrow > 0

Comment: Obrigado a todos resolvido.